# How to Dictionary only training?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I want to train the basic translation system with only a glossary.

The language pair is ENtoKO. I trained 1,700 sentences in the dictionary tab in the manner described in the article.

## I did not select anything in the "Training" tab.

https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1166938-hub-building-a-custom-system-using-a-dictionary-o

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JlCB.png)

However, expectation and system did not translate the terms. and unlike the document (Microsoft Translator Hub User Guide.pdf), the training completes much time.

***Dictionary only training***: *You can now train a custom translation system when with just a dictionary and no other parallel documents. There is no minimum size for that dictionary, one entry is enough. Just upload the dictionary, which is an Excel file with the language identifier as column header, include it in your training set, and hit train. The training completes very quickly, then you can deploy and use your system with that dictionary. The dictionary applies the translation you provided with 100% probability, regardless of context. This type of training does not produce bleu score and this option only available if MS models are available for given language pair.*

1. Why this training only losing silp Dicionary would like to know. If the update is a feature that is not the intended schedule?
2. In addition, I am wondering if there is a plan to introduce the Dictionary application function to the NMT Api function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing NMT is available now by using [Custom Translator (Preview)](http://aka.ms/CustomTranslator) and we expect the Dictionary feature to be available when Custom Translator is Generally Available.

You do need to be using the [Microsoft Translator Text API v3](http://aka.ms/Translatorv3Migration) and Custom Translator supports language pairs where [NMT languages](http://aka.ms/TranslatorLanguages) are available today (Korean is a NMT language).

Thank you.

Comment: Is the Dictionary feature up and running now ? I am trying to use Dictionary only trained machine and it is not giving desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can customize our en-ko general domain baseline with your dictionary. Please follow our [quick start documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/quickstart-build-deploy-custom-model)

Comment: I created a new model with dictionary only training with small dictionary file (6 strings) for testing purpose. I still do not see the dictionary provided strings being prioritized for translations. I still got the general translations instead of the ones provided in the dictionary file. I tested for en-ko language pair. Also, I used the Microsoft Translator Text API v3 with custom translator.